# How to select the download location in flask send_file?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on a flask based UI and there I am downloading a text file using send_file function.

This is my directory setup:

```
    /static
      /design.css
    /templates
      /index.html
      /upload.html
      /engine.html
   /output
      /text_file.txt
    /main.py
```

Below is the code:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    path = "output\\text_file.txt"
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
```

And below is related html button which is initiating the download:

```
 <button>
        <a href="{{ url_for('.download_file') }}" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Download Source Text
        </a>
 </button>
```

Now this function is directly downloading the file in **downloads** folder of my local C drive. But I want to get an option to select the location like below:

[image]

(image taken from google)

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export CSV to absolute path in Flask, using Content-disposition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471736/how-to-export-csv-to-absolute-path-in-flask-using-content-disposition)

Comment: `I want to get an option to select the location like below` I think what you're describing is a browser setting, which cannot be controlled from the server.  At most the server can specify the downloaded *filename* but not the *path*.  Any more functionality in the `save as` dialogue would be controlled by the end-user's browser config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to save the downloaded file is decided by a browser and server-side application cannot change this--and this is a feature, not a bug.

You think about it--say a server application can pick a location to save a file, what if my website saves an exe file to your C:\Windows folder? The consequence is disastrous...

Some modern browsers allow users to set a default download path. If you discover that your file is saved to a folder, such as `Downloads`, without asking you, most likely you have this browser feature enabled.

Comment: So can I disable this feature? so that next time it will ask for location.

Comment: Yes, you can disable this feature in your browser. If you use Firefox, you can find the setting in Preferences -> Downloads section.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much Alex Kong. Enable the always ask option and it worked like charm.